# What is the underlying database datomic is implemented in?

Tags: database, clojure, datomic

My understanding is that datomic is implemented on top of an existing key-value store. Does anyone know what that is?

Comment: It's hard to get a clear overview of Datomic's architecture without watching hour-long conference keynotes. This [recent summary](http://www.flyingmachinestudios.com/programming/datomic-for-five-year-olds/) is gold.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Datomic isn't built around a specific key-value store. It supports multiple storage backends.

Currently supported backends are various SQL databases, [DynamoDB](http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/), [Riak](http://basho.com/riak/), [Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/), and [Infinispan memory cluster](http://www.jboss.org/infinispan). The free edition of Datomic uses an embedded [H2 SQL database](http://www.h2database.com). More backends may be supported in the future.

Datomic is designed to allow you to switch from one storage backend to another by exporting/importing the data.

You may want to check out 
http://www.datomic.com/overview.html and http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html

Comment: Could you expand on "an embedded SQL database"?

Comment: I believe the free version stores data into an H2 SQL database that's running embedded inside the transactor process.

Comment: When you purchase the service - do you know what it is running on?

Comment: Datomic currently isn't sold as a service. You are responsible for setting up and running your own transactor, on your own server. If you want to run it on AWS, datomic provides some tools to simplify the deployment process, see: http://docs.datomic.com/aws.html

Comment: @mtyaka can you run datomic on any other cloud like GCE, AZURE, etc?